# agent.add() not printing, also there is no output for api implementation

Tags: javascript, api, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

Below is my code on dialogflow, when I enter my training sentence it will print Not available, and I have no idea why. I have added "axios": "0.21.1" to my package , change node version from 10 to 8, and I also added const axios = require('axios'); as my first line in index.js. Thank you for your help!

```
function rhymingWordHandler(agent){
const word = agent.parameters.word;
console.log('please pass');
agent.add(`Here is the name of ${word}`);
return axios.get(`https://api.magicthegathering.io/v1/cards/${word}`)
.then((result) => {
  result.data.map(wordObj => {
  //Object.keys(result.data).map((wordObj) => {
    agent.add(wordObj.card.name);
  });
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Guys in case someone also has this question, for my api website result.data is already a card obj so I dont need map tp get me the card obj. so just do console.log(result.data.card.name) should print the name of the card you are looking for.